# TortoiseGit: Overlay icons work for folders, not for files

Tags: icons, registry, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit and the overlay icons show up for the folders and not the files. I came across this page http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit/ which I tried, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Right now in my registry/ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers, Tortoise icons take precedence over any other application.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason might be that you excluded the folder/drive type on `TortoiseGit settings -> Icon overlays` (https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay; you might need to check "Network drive", "Drives A: and B:" and/or "Removable Drive" depending on the drive type). When "Show excluded as normal" is checked, all folders will have a "normal" overlay icon and files don't have any overlay icon.

Please also see https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#ovlnotshowing

Answer (score 0):

I came here using Windows 11 and I had the same issue.  No file icon overlays but the icon overlays for the folders were present.   [MrTux's first link](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay) showed the Icon Overlays screen in Git->Settings and I noticed that my status cache had been set to None.  Setting back to Default got things working again for me.

[image]